# Input is not recognized when typed in by user

Tags: c#

So, I am a new student in Software and I'm doing my assignment, this may seem like a simple question but it is wrecking my head.

The assignment is for the user to input 6 school subject and the grade they got for each, then to calculate the grades into points and display. I feel that I have the skeleton of the code done, however when I run the program no matter what input I put in the answer always seems to be invalid.

Thanks for your help,
Joe

Here is the code I am using, its being used in Visual Studio.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace caoAssignment
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Delcaring variables //
            string subIn, sub1, sub2, sub3, sub4, sub5, sub6;
            string gradeIn, grade1, grade2, grade3, grade4, grade5, grade6;
            int pointsIn, points1, points2, points3, points4, points5, points6;
            int x;
            string doAgain = "";

            // Getting the user to input necessary information. 2 peices needed. 

            do
            {
                x = 1;
                while (x <= 6)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Please enter a subject ");
                    subIn = Console.ReadLine();

                    Console.WriteLine("Please enter the grade you got in that                      subject (H1 - O8) ");
                    gradeIn = Console.ReadLine();

                    // Processing the grades in points //

                    if (gradeIn == "H1")
                        pointsIn = 100;

                    if (gradeIn == "H2")
                        pointsIn = 88;

                    if (gradeIn == "H3")
                        pointsIn = 77;

                    if (gradeIn == "H4")
                        pointsIn = 66;

                    if (gradeIn == "H5")
                        pointsIn = 56;

                    if (gradeIn == "H6")
                        pointsIn = 46;

                    if (gradeIn == "H7")
                        pointsIn = 37;

                    if (gradeIn == "H8")
                        pointsIn = 0;

                    if (gradeIn == "O1")
                        pointsIn = 56;

                    if (gradeIn == "O2")
                        pointsIn = 46;

                    if (gradeIn == "O3")
                        pointsIn = 37;

                    if (gradeIn == "O4")
                        pointsIn = 28;

                    if (gradeIn == "O5")
                        pointsIn = 20;

                    if (gradeIn == "O6")
                        pointsIn = 12;

                    if (gradeIn == "O7")
                        pointsIn = 0;

                    if (gradeIn == "O8")
                        pointsIn = 0;

                    else
                        Console.WriteLine("Input is wrong, please redo. ");


                    // Assigning each grade,subject and points depending on what X is //
                    if (x == 1)
                    {
                        subIn = sub1;
                        gradeIn = grade1;
                        pointsIn = points1;

                    }

                    if (x == 2)
                    {
                        subIn = sub2;
                        gradeIn = grade2;
                        pointsIn = points2;

                    }

                    if (x == 3)
                    {
                        subIn = sub3;
                        gradeIn = grade3;
                        pointsIn = points3;

                    }

                    if (x == 4)
                    {
                        subIn = sub4;
                        gradeIn = grade4;
                        pointsIn = points4;

                    }

                    if (x == 5)
                    {
                        subIn = sub5;
                        gradeIn = grade5;
                        pointsIn = points5;

                    }

                    if (x == 6)
                    {
                        subIn = sub6;
                        gradeIn = grade6;
                        pointsIn = points6;

                    }

                    x++;
                } // End of the while loop

                Console.WriteLine("Do again? (Y/N) ");
                doAgain = Console.ReadLine();

            } // End of the do loop
            while (doAgain == "Y"); 

            // Command to keep the program open for the user //
            Console.ReadKey();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This can't be the code you are actually running, since it doesn't compile. Post the code you ran to increase the chance of getting a correct answer. If you use the debugger to step through the code and see what happens, you'll see the error that you've made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this part of the code:

```
if (gradeIn == "O7")
    pointsIn = 0;

if (gradeIn == "O8")
    pointsIn = 0;
else
    Console.WriteLine("Input is wrong, please redo. ");
```

What happens if grade is not "08"? The `else` statement is only applied to the last `if` statement. Also a good rule of thumb is to always add curly braces after `if`, `else`, etc, to indicate the scope and avoid mistakes.

If you chain the `if` statements with `else`, you are telling the program that the next `if` is only going to apply if the previous was not applied.

```
if (gradeIn == "O7")
{
    pointsIn = 0;
}
else if (gradeIn == "O8")
{
    pointsIn = 0;
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Input is wrong, please redo. ");
}
```

When comparing strings using the `==` operator, the comparison is case sensitive. To make it case insensitive, use the overloaded `string.Equals` method:

```
if(string.Equals(gradeIn, "O7", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
```

Comment: So the problem with the inputs was that I had not assigned pointsIn as anything yet, but I have tried your case sensitive command and it does the job.

Thanks very much to both of you :)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, project should not compile, as code is trying to use unassigned variables. Sub1

```
//Assigning each grade,subject and points depending on what X is 
if (x == 1)
{
subIn = sub1;
gradeIn = grade1;
pointsIn = points1;
}
```

Secondly

```
subIn = sub2;
```

This should be the other way. 
The first value is the variable you want to assign second value.

Comment: The main problem I am having is that no matter what I input for the grade it always outputs invalid, I have tried H1,h1 and " h1" but its always the same.

Comment: Is your project compiling? the code supplied should not build. chances are u are running the last successful build.
I would suggest you start from scratch and build pieces of code and test them out. this way you will be able to find the problem faster.

Comment: Yeah its compiling fine now, however I dont know where to put the output commands for the subject, grades and points